# How can I automate Google Sign page in karate within mobile

Tags: android, karate

I am looking to automate below google sign-in page with in mobile using karate , but I am unable to it . Can someone kindly give me some tips\tricks for same?

I launch my company app and from the app I click a link which takes me to below google sign in screen,

[image]

[image]
I tried all below methods,but nothing seems to work

```
* driver.click("//android.widget.FrameLayout")
* driver.click("//android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='0']")
* driver.input("//android.widget.FrameLayout",'Text')
* driver.input("//android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='0']")
* driver.input("//android.view.View[@index='0']"
```

I found solution for same ,may be helpfull for others

```
  * switchFrame("//android.widget.FrameLayout")
  * input("#identifierId","littlemaster@gmail.com")
  * driver.click("//android.widget.Button[@text='NEXT']")
```

Comment: I found the solution , may be its helpfull for other as well

Comment: * switchFrame("//android.widget.FrameLayout")
  * input("#identifierId","littlemaster@gmail.com")
  * driver.click("//android.widget.Button[@text='NEXT']")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  * switchFrame("//android.widget.FrameLayout")
  * input("#identifierId","littlemaster@gmail.com")
  * driver.click("//android.widget.Button[@text='NEXT']")
```